# Extreme slob file confusion

Tags: file-format

I have, in my endless search for the english dictionary, come across this link https://github.com/itkach/slob/wiki/Dictionaries#how-to-download

It has a slob file of the English dictionary available for download, but I don't even know what that is?

What exactly is a slob file and how do you convert it into a text or database file?

Thanks!

## EDIT

PyDictionary solved my issue. I was able to use it to parse

Anyways, my question still remains though. What exactly is a slob file and why does google not even register it as a word?

Answer (score 1):

from here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aarddict/GvmaYy0BQIs Slob is influenced by both Aard Dictionary format and OpenZIM and can store any content, not just text or html.

This is the file format spec for Aard http://aarddict.org/aardtools/doc/aardformat.html and this one is for ZIM http://www.openzim.org/wiki/ZIM_file_format

Answer (score 1):

Slob files are used by an application called **Aard2 Dictionary**, see http://aarddict.org/

> Slob (**s**orted **l**ist **o**f **b**lobs) is a read-only, compressed data store with
>   dictionary-like interface to look up content by text keys.
>   ([source](https://github.com/itkach/slob]))

You can use **Aard2 Dictionary** for reading for example Wikipedia offline. And many other dictionaries and encyclopaedias, too. That means you don’t need an internet connection to have a lot of information on your phone. You get a smartphone that is independent of internet, staying *smart* while being offline. It mostly faster to search and load an article which is saved on your phone, instead of loading it from the internet.